# Defining Literal Text outside its Control

Tags: c#, asp.net, literals, ascx, string-literals

I have created a literal inside a control (finance-box.ascx)

```
<tr><td class="title">Deposit</td></tr>
<tr><td class="fig"><asp:Literal id="one_deposit" runat="server"/></td></tr>
```

I have called this Control into a page (finance.aspx)

Can I define the literal value inside the finance.cs.aspx page as this control will be called on more than one page?

Possible Code in Finance.cs.aspx

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Finance_Box.one_modal_monthly.Text = "&pound;3234.00";
        Finance_Box.one_deposit.Text = "&pound;3234.00";
    }
```

Comment: Apologies. It says that the control doesn't exists in current content

Answer (score 1):

You could expose the control as a property, but better yet, just expose a property around the thing for the type you need, a string. So, in the control...

```
public string LiteralText {
  get { return myLiteral.Text; }
  set { myLiteral.Text = value; }
}
```

Then in your pages you can use them on the control declaration or in code-behind:

```
<controls:MyControl runat="server" ID="myControl" LiteralText="Some text!" />

myControl.LiteralText = "Some text!";
```

Comment: Hi Grant, Thank you for your response. That makes sense. One question that I'm having trouble is with defining the 'LiteralText' in the cs.aspx would it go in Page_Load ? It's current returning 'Object reference required for the non static field'

Answer (score 0):

You should create a property on you user control as follows

```
public string depositeLiteral
{
    get { return one_deposit.Text; }
    set { one_deposit.Text = value; }
}
```

and while adding your user control to you page you can set it's value

```
var lobjucName = (finance-box.ascx)LoadControl("~/UserControl/finance-box.ascx.ascx");
lobjucModelPopulator.depositeLiteral= "";
```